# How to multiply 3 matrices using shared memory in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiprocessing

I want to multiply 3 matrices (like E = AxBxC) using shared memory in multiprocessing method. I can do it with 2 matrices but when I want to repeat the same procedure for the third matrix, I got stuck and don't know how to handle the shared array.
I know I must use the multiprocessing array but don't know how to manage it.
Here is the way I used array in my code:

```
mp_arr_one = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_int, 3*3)
```

and then in my function:

```
arr = numpy.frombuffer(mp_arr_one.get_obj(), dtype=ctypes.c_int)
res = arr.reshape((3,3))
```

Everything's good for first part (D = AxB) but when I want to calculate E = DxC, the code goes wrong and the result is completely incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `numpy` with an optimized  BLAS (e.g. OpenBLAS, BLAS ATLAS, MKL) that supports multi-threading.

Matrix multiplication will be parallelized, and because it includes extensive architecture dependent optimizations, this approach will be faster than explicitly managing shared memory in Python with `multiprocessing.Array`. By the way, you should use an optimized BLAS implementation with `numpy`, if speed is an issue, even in single thread execution, so there is no way around it.